# Solving hadoop open issues

Tags: hadoop

I have been learning hadoop for sometime and trying to get more hands on. Is there a way we can take up open issues in map reduce and solve them ? Is there any JIRA link for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will be welcome to do so

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

http://hadoop.apache.org/issue_tracking.html